# Javascript 'function name': f,

Tags: javascript

I have this code here below.

```
  var john = {
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: 'Steinbeck',
   mass: 98,
   height: 1.82,
   bmicalc: function(){
   this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * 
   this.height)
   return this.bmi;
}};

var mark = {
   firstName: 'Mark',
   lastName: 'Scofield',
   mass: 70,
   height: 1.98,
   bmicalc: function() {
    this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * 
    this.height);
    return this.bmi;
 }
}
john.bmicalc();
mark.bmicalc();
console.log(john, mark);
```

Im not sure what the problem is within the code, been sat here trying to figure out where its going wrong. The output is not giving values from the functions, but does this instead:

```
 {firstName: "John", lastName: "Steinbeck", mass: 98, height: 1.82, bmicalc: 
ƒ, …} 
{firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Scofield", mass: 70, height: 1.98, 
bmicalc: ƒ, …}
```

instead if `bmicalc: ƒ, …}` it should be the value calculated by the function.

what the output should be (TAKE NOTICE OF BMICALC):

```
{firstName: "John", lastName: "Steinbeck", mass: 98, height: 1.82, bmicalc: 
29.585798816568044}
{firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Scofield", mass: 70, height: 1.98, 
bmicalc: 17.8553208856239}
```

Comment: you are logging the objects and you are expecting the bmi value?

Comment: the formula inside the function should return the values when calling either `console.log(john)` or `console.log(mark)`.. i have updated the question to see the output

Comment: But the function still exists, it is not like it will disappear because you called it..... You are setting bmi.... so that is what it will be.... You can see it in the log `bmi: 17.8553208856239`

Comment: right... i clicked the arrow poiting to the right and it showed me the value :|

Comment: The code is working as expected. If you do not want the function to be there, than you need to remove the function or change the .bmi to replace the bmicalc property. So it is working as designed.

Comment: It logs as `{ bmi: 29.585798816568044
bmicalc: ƒ ()
firstName: "John"
height: 1.82
lastName: "Steinbeck"
mass: 98 }` which is 100% expected.

Comment: @Vladimir it works like that in Javascript. You assigned a function to the object as a property `bmicalc`. The fact that you executed that function doesn't mean that object prop will be replaced with value of that function.

Comment: looks like you might want to assign bmicalc as a getter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not call in the code but you assign a function, that's why the function body is displayed and this is correct. Attempts to call a function while defining an object will end with problems with the meaning of the word "this".

You repeat the same code repeatedly, that's why you should write it differently, for example, as below.

```js
function Person(firstName,lastName,mass,height) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.mass=mass;
    this.height=height;
    this.bmiCalc=function(){
        return (this.mass / (this.height * this.height));
    }
};

var sophia = new Person('Sophia','Nicoll',70,1.78);
var stefano = new Person('Stefano','Bonetti',80,1.82);

console.log(sophia.firstName,sophia.lastName,sophia.bmiCalc());
console.log(stefano.firstName,stefano.lastName,stefano.bmiCalc());
```

Answer (score 0):

To see values in console use

```
console.log(john.bmicalc(), mark.bmicalc());
```

Comment: But if I call `'John'` it should also include the values inside the whole array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling the object itself. The object is just letting you know that "bmicalc" is a function within the object, and is not returning the calculations done inside the function.

Also this is an object and not an array. Perhaps this is where your confusion is coming from.

EDIT:

For clarifications sake. You are calling the definition of the object, not the instance of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the object such that bmicalc is a method of that object. To see the value calculated, you need to call that method explicitly.

console.log(john.bmicalc() , mark.bmicalc)

If you log the object you will see bmicalc is a method defined on it.